# CodeIgniter function not taking parameters

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, function

I defined this function

```
function login_user($emailusername, $password) { }
```

the function uses the variables but, when I try to call it using

```
$this->login->login_user('username', 'password');
```

it returns an error saying that those variables are undefined in the function.

EDIT: I set the function in a login model

I get these errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: password
>   Filename: models/login.php
>   Line Number: 20
>
> line 20: $pass = crypt($password, $hash['password']);
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: username
>   Filename: models/login.php
>   Line Number: 26
>
> line 26: if ($user_data['username'] == $emailusername || $user_data['email'] == $emailusername) {
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: email
>   Filename: models/login.php
>   Line Number: 26
>
> line 26: if ($user_data['username'] == $emailusername || $user_data['email'] == $emailusername) {

This is the function

```
     function login_user($emailusername, $password) {
        //To initiate session set this cookie
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT password FROM usrs WHERE username = '$emailusername' or email = '$emailusername'"); 

        $hash = $query->result();

        $pass = crypt($password, $hash['password']);

        $nq = $this->db->query("SELECT usr_id, username, email from usrs WHERE email = '$emailusername' or username = '$emailusername' and password = '$pass'");
        $user_data = $nq->result(); 

        if($emailusername&&$password) {
            if ($user_data['username'] == $emailusername || $user_data['email'] == $emailusername) {
                if($hash['password'] == $pass) {

                    $_SESSION['login'] = True;
                    $_SESSION['uid'] = $user_data['usr_id'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $user_data['username'];


                    return True;
                } else
                    return False; 
            } else
                return False;
        } else 
            return False; 
    }
```

Comment: What class is that function in? is the class called `login`?

Comment: More specific error please 'in the function' is not that clear to me.

Comment: @Kush The class is called login is that a problem?

Comment: Maybe you didn't load the `login` class? if it's a model then use  `$this->load->model("login");`. BTW: please clarify things, Where did you call the function, where did you create it and what's exactly the error?

Comment: which line is line 20? dun make us guessing ..

Comment: @AzizAG I've added the whole function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not in your variables.
There is no index calldes 'password' in your $hash table;
Check Your $hash table first.

```
$hash = $query->result();
```

function return object array consist

```
$hash->password = '';
```

If want to get single row and result is to be array use row_array() function

```
$hash = $query->row_array();
```

this returns

```
$hash['password']
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue originates from this line:

```
$hash = $query->result();
```

[As per the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html), `result()` does the following:

> This function returns the query result as an array of **objects**, or **an empty array** on failure. Typically you'll use this in a foreach loop...

So, `$hash` contains no indices named `password`, `username`, or `email` - hence the error messages you're receiving.

If you're only concerned with the first row returned from that query (which is my assumption), you can use `row_array()` to return only the first record and *as an array*, which will make those indices available, like this:

```
$hash = $query->row_array();
// $hash['password'], $hash['username'], and $hash['email'] are now available
```

Comment: Thanks to you too but the other guy answered before :P

Comment: @Supremekhaoz: No problem - glad my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using codeignitor, if the function is in a controller 'Login' then use

```
$this->login_user('username', 'password');
```

If the function is in a library, then make sure that you have loaded the library and the name of the instance is 'login'

And if you have included the file directly then just make an object and call the method

```
$loginObj = new login();
$loginObj->login_user('username', 'password');
```

Cheers,

Vedant

Comment: The errors referenced in the question have nothing to do with this.

Comment: Ya I can see that now, the question was edited after I answered it.

Comment: No problem - just thought I'd point it out (rather than downvote).